# Share a domain for a old PHP project and its Zend refactored part

Tags: php, zend-framework, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm refactoring an old project developed in procedural PHP, with a new object oriented approach with Zend.

The website have two main section: 
- Miscellaneous pages, lots of old pages still online on the main domain (www)
- A forum section, the part i refactorised with Zend on a forum subdomain

The goal is to refactor the whole website on a main Zend project which would cover the two subdomains.

Now i have to refactor some of the pages of the main domain, and because the domains have separated virtualhosts: the www domain is set to a specific directory and the forum domain is set to another directory (the Zend one), each one with custom URL rewriting.

The obvious solution would be to merge the old pages directories with the forum directory, but i can't because it would break the folder architecture of Zend.

The ideal solution would be to add a regexp clause in the main domain's vitualhost to redirect some urls of the www to the directory of the Zend project directory, but i haven't find a way to do it yet.

Is there a other way? I also can create some temporary subdomain to host the refactored pages but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info on how the old pages are setup? Are they just static HTML files or PHP scripts? Why can't you just copy them into the public folder of the ZF app?

Comment: There are hundreds of old php pages and scripts to move which use dozens of poorly SEO optimised htaccess url rewriting rules.
I guess i could rewrite these URLs in my bootstrap file, but i think things will quickly goes messy, plus i have to rewrite those URLs in the future.

Comment: As long as those URLs don't clash with new ones you want to use, you should be able to copy the scripts into public and paste the rewrite rules in your htaccess file above the ZF ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i choose a mixed solution, i'll use temporary subdomains for some parts until i could refactor in one time the rest of the old pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it.
Why don't you make a clean refactor on your local env, then deploy it and make the DNS migration ? Why would you make old and new pieces of code cohabit ? You said it : "The goal is to refactor the whole website on a main Zend project which would cover the two subdomains". Then go on ! Refactor, deploy, and redirect the old domain names to the new one !

Comment: It's what i want, but you know, business constraints.
The website is too huge to be refactored in one time, because the client's incomes are solely based on this website, sales sold him this way of work...